# Change _Key words and phrases_ in amsart

Tags: amsart

I'd like to know a way to change *Key words and phrases* that appears when I use `\keywords` in amsart (because I'm writing in foreign language).

For table of contents and references, for example, we can change names by `\renewcommand{\contentsname}{NewContentsName}` and `\renewcommand{\refname}{NewRefName}`. Is there a similar way for keywords?

Comment: `\renewcommand{\keywordsname}{Whatever}`

Comment: @egreg Thank you. What an obvious name it is! I'll accept the answer and close this question if you post is as an answer.

Comment: Sorry, no time now. I'll be back in a few hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As egreg commented,

```
\renewcommand{\keywordsname}{Whatever}
```

works fine.